# How do you use an OR statement between two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to throw a OR statement that stretches over two columns, been trying sorts of variation but unable to get the correct syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM exampleTable    
WHERE firstColumn IN ('example1', 'example2')
OR secondColumn = 'example3'
```

I get an error on the second line saying " Incorrect syntax near ' (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)."

Comment: The N'example1' (the N part), are you sure if the sql query is valid? It would be helpful if you provide a exact/similar query you are using.

Comment: @mane Yea I dont know what the N thing was about, cant ask my co-worker now...Thanks for the notice!

Comment: N'string value' is SQL Server notation to denote nvarchar type for the string value - not sure if MySQL has the same though.

Comment: This query should be valid, are you posting exactly what you were trying?

Comment: I just tested this on my mysqldb, it's valid.

Comment: I agree, there is no syntax error in the code presented above, the error is coming from some other place (or the exact query isn't visible to us)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM exampleTable    
WHERE firstColumn IN ('example1', 'example2')
OR secondColumn in  ('example3')
```

Comment: changing = to IN(  ) has zero effect on precedence in that query.